# Scala: use case class from Main

Tags: scala, object, sbt, program-entry-point, case-class

In my project there is a Main object:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

and another one:

```
object Abc {
  abstract class BAbcTest
  case object Meow extends BAbcTest

  ...


  def domeow(b: BAbcTest): BAbcTest = b match { ... }
}
```

How can I call `domeow` from `Main`? I am using sbt and when I type in `run` there, it just prints "Hello World.".

I tried to write `domeow(Meow)` in the Main object but it keeps saying

> not found: value Meow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `Abc.domeow(Abc.Meow)` inside the `Main` object. Everything inside the `Main` will be executed in the `main method` as `Main extends App`.

You have to do `Abc.Meow` inorder to refer to `Meow` object from `Main` object or `import` `Abc` using `import Abc._` inside the `Main`

```
 object Main extends App {
    println("Hello world")
    Abc.domeow(Abc.Meow)
  }
```

or import Abc._

```
object Main extends App {
    println("Hello world")

    import Abc._

    Abc.domeow(Meow)
  }


  object Abc {
    abstract class BAbcTest
    case object Meow extends BAbcTest
    def domeow(b: BAbcTest): BAbcTest = b match { case Meow => Meow }
  }
```

do `Abc.test(1)` inside the `Main` object.

As `Main` extends `App`. All code inside the Main will be executed inside the `main` method of the object `Main`. So when you do `sbt run` all the code inside the `Main` object executes.

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello world")
  println(Abc.test(1))
}

object Abc {
  def test(a: Int): Int = a match { ... }
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> object Abc {
    def test(a: Int): Int = a match { case 1  => 1}
  }
defined object Abc

scala> object Main extends App {
    println("Hello world")
    println(Abc.test(1))
  }
defined object Main

scala< Main.main(Array(""))
Hello world
1
```

Comment: Okay, now i figured out it is all about the case classes I am using - any ideas on this?

Comment: Very helpful  - isn't there a way to write it without "Abc." before every usage?

Comment: Thank you so much - this was very helpfful.

Comment: @今天春天   well you can use `import Abc._` to just use `Meow` as function parameter.

Comment: @今天春天 Accept the solution if its helpful .. :)